# Replacing bad words in a string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, file, nsstring

I have a game with a public highscore list where I allow layers to enter their name (or anything unto 12 characters). I am trying to create a couple of functions to filter out bad words from a list of bad words

I have in a text file. I have two methods:

One to read in the text file:

```
-(void) getTheBadWordsAndSaveForLater {

    badWordsFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"badwords" ofType:@"txt"];
    badWordFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:badWordsFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    badwords =[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:badWordFile];
    badwords = [badWordFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];


    NSLog(@"Number Of Words Found in file: %i",[badwords count]);

    for (NSString* words in badwords) {

        NSLog(@"Word in Array----- %@",words);
    }


}
```

And one to check a word `(NSString*)` agains the list that I read in:

```
-(NSString *) removeBadWords :(NSString *) string {


    // If I hard code this line below, it works....
    // *****************************************************************************
    //badwords =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"shet",@"shat",@"shut",nil];
    // *****************************************************************************


    NSLog(@"checking: %@",string);

    for (NSString* words in badwords) {

       string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:words withString:@"-" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

        NSLog(@"Word in Array: %@",words);
    }

     NSLog(@"Cleaned Word Returned: %@",string);
    return string;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I hardcode the words into an array (see commented out above) then it works like a charm. But when I use the array I read in with the first method, it does't work - the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:words` does not seem to have an effect. I have traced out to the log so I can see if the words are coming thru and they are... That one line just doesn't seem to see the words unless I hardcore into the array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense.  You load badWordFile from a file at badWordsFilePath, and then load badwords from the file located at badWordsFile.  Then overwrite that value (whatever it is) with badWordsFile processed through componentsSeparatedByString.

Comment: But it may be that your main problem is failing to remove carriage returns from the elements of the read array (that was probably created using Notepad or some such that adds carriage returns).  Try `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` with `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` (on each individual word).

Comment: BTW, this scheme is fraught with peril.  Many perfectly legitimate words contain "bad" words inside them.  And even (slightly) "bad" words are perfectly OK in a different context:  "The moon on the breast of the new fallen snow, Gave the lustre of mid-day to objects below".

Comment: Thanks for the suggests HOTLICKS - could ya tell I'm kinda new to XCODE? As for the scheme being drought with peril, I agree and welcome a better suggestion - I know that if I don't put any safeguard in there, it will get abused.

Comment: HOTLICKS - your first comment on the badWordsFilePath, I thought I ended to alloc init everything - not true?

Comment: @user2887097 You need to "instantiate" it somehow. One way is alloc/init. Another is a method like `componentsSeparatedByString`, which instantiates it for you. But you don't need to instantiate with alloc/init, if you're only going to discard that and replace with the results of `componentsSeparatedByString`. BTW, if you want to get HotLicks' attention, you need to put an "@" before "HotLicks", or else HotLicks won't be notified that you sent a comment.

Comment: Just a more general comment: you should *really* do this on the server. You cannot anticipate how people will abuse your services, and so you cannot adequately protect it from the client side. Never trust the client.

Comment: Any time you assign a new value to a pointer with `=`, the old value, and the object it addressed is no longer accessible through that pointer (though there may be another copy of  the pointer somewhere else).  You really need to understand the concept of pointers better if you will be coding in Objective-C, since it's all about pointers.

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`, btw.  Use `loadBadWords` instead.  `get` is reserved for very specific uses and this isn't it.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You have two lines:

   ```
   badwords =[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:badWordFile];
   badwords = [badWordFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
   ```

   There's no point in doing that `initWithContentsOfFile` if you're just going to replace it with the `componentsSeparatedByString` on the next line. Plus, `initWithContentsOfFile` assumes the file is a property list (plist), but the rest of your code clearly assumes it's a newline separated text file. Personally, I would have used the plist format (it obviates the need to trim the whitespace from the individual words), but you can use whichever you prefer. But use one or the other, but not both.

   If you're staying with the newline separated list of bad words, then just get rid of that line that says `initWithContentsOfFile`, you disregard the results of that, anyway. Thus:

   ```
   - (void)getTheBadWordsAndSaveForLater {

       // these should be local variables, so get rid of your instance variables of the same name

       NSString *badWordsFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"badwords" ofType:@"txt"];
       NSString *badWordFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:badWordsFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

       // calculate `badwords` solely from `componentsSeparatedByString`, not `initWithContentsOfFile`

       badwords = [badWordFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

       // confirm what we got

       NSLog(@"Found %i words: %@", [badwords count], badwords);
   }
   ```
2. You might want to look for whole word occurrences only, rather than just the presence of the bad word anywhere:

   ```
   - (NSString *) removeBadWords:(NSString *) string {

       NSLog(@"checking: %@ for occurrences of these bad words: %@", string, badwords);

       for (NSString* badword in badwords) {
           NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b%@\\b", badword];
           string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:searchString
                                                      withString:@"-"
                                                         options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
       }

       NSLog(@"resulted in: %@", string);

       return string;
   }
   ```

   This uses a "regular expression" search, where `\b` stands for "a boundary between words". Thus, `\bhell\b` (or, because backslashes have to be quoted in a `NSString` literal, that's `@"\\bhell\\b"`) will search for the word "hell" that is a separate word, but won't match "hello", for example.
3. Note, above, I am also logging `badwords` to see if that variable was reset somehow. That's the only thing that would make sense given the symptoms you describe, namely that the loading of the bad words from the text file works but replace process fails. So examine `badwords` before you replace and make sure it's still set properly.